# Is there a minimum amount a muscle can move? And thus, gaps in our movement?

Tags: neuroscience, muscles, movement

Lately I've been thinking about something, based on my knowledge my chain of reasoning works like this...

When you want to move a muscle your brain sends an electrical nervous impulse along the chain of nerve cells to the muscle you want to move.

A nervous impulse is nothing other then a jolt of electricity, the voltage is uniform and the only difference is the rate the jolts are sent, resulting in faster movement.

When a muscle is hit by electricity it's reaction is to contract, this is what creates movement.

Given all this, is our movement continuous or quantized? Let's say one jolt moves my finger 1 degree, another jolt would move it another degree. Would that not make it impossible to move my finger 1.5 degrees? To me it stands to reason that while you could shut off the power to your finger at any time, making it theoretically continuous, there must be a minimum amount of frequency by the impulses needed to cause any movement.

If this is true then the movement of our bodies is the microscopic snapping through possible positions. And therefore there must be a finite number of possible positions our bodies can take. Like a knob that can only click it's way through the pre-determined positions on the dial.

Is all this true? Do nervous impulses work like I think they do? Are there things about nervous impulses or muscles we don't know? Are we capable of only positioning ourselves in this quantized way? Has anyone proven any of the things I have said? Please consider you answer carefully.

Personally I hope our ability to position ourselves is continuous.

Comment: That's not even close to how muscle signals work, you may want to look up something called muscle recruitment or muscle fiber recruitment.

Comment: What about the rest of my question?